# Compiler either skips for loop or does not run code inside (Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, syntax

I am attempting to write a code in Java to take a word and scramble it. I have a for loop to loop through the word:

```
        String inWord = getWord.nextLine();

        //loop as many times as x < length of word
        for(int x = 0; x >= inWord.length(); x++){

            //random number between 0 and length of word - 1
            int randomChar = randChar.nextInt(inWord.length() - 1);

            out.print("in the first for loop, randomChar is equal to " + randomChar + ", and x is equal to " + x);
```

The loop continues with some other irrelevant code, then is closed. However, when run, the console only takes a word as input then terminates the program. Nothing is printed. Is something wrong with my for loop?

Comment: A string starts with 0 and goes till `.length()` a simple mistake you did is that you check if value is greater than equal to length . This means if your word is `abcd` you tend to check `0 >= 4` which would always be false.

Comment: Did you really check the code through out before posting it on SO ? Its too simple a mistake and would most propably - be removed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have switched the for-loop condition, it should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < inWord.length(); x++) {
```

Note that the second part of the loop, here `x < inWord.length()` is the condition for *when the loop should run*, not *when the loop should break*. The loop runs as long as that condition is `true`.

---

Additionally,

```
int randomChar = randChar.nextInt(inWord.length() - 1);
```

Should be:

```
int randomChar = randChar.nextInt(inWord.length());
```

Otherwise you won't have a chance of returning the last character in the string.

[Random.nextInt(int bound)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) documentation says:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your operator is reversed, use <.

Comment: There's no need to use `<=`, simply using `<` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `x` to `0` in the first part of your for loop, then in your conditional, you checked to see if it's greater than or equal to the word length (`x >= inWord.length()`). Since that condition is almost never met (i.e. the word has to be length 0, which will almost never happen) the loop won't be entered. You probably meant `x < inWord.length()` instead.

Comment: Formatting tip: Use backticks - `\`` - in your answers to format code. Writing `<` without using backticks often interprets it as a HTML tag, which is what has happened in your answer here. If you want to write a real '<', use `&lt;` instead